# VS code Editor cannot open and developer tools pops up with an error message

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code

When i open my VS code, it shows that "The Editor could not be opened due to unexpected error; try again. Unable to write folder settings because no resource is provided and check Developer tools also pops up showing this error:

1. DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://ticino.blob.core.windows.net/sourcemaps/e18005f%E2%80%A6/core/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout

I tried googling but a whole page of script pops up of which i know nothing

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly know what the issue was since I can't tell if you were making something before-hand or if you just installed but I'll give you a few helpful tips

1: If you were working on a web app, you need to enable CSS & Javascript sourcemaps in whatever browser you are using. There are many tutorials to teach you how to do this.

2: If VSCode gives you the error but still opens, try to open a folder or a workspace file, as [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/414) says that opening a workspace should fix the issue.

3: If you just installed VSCode, uninstall it and try again. It's more than likely that VSCode didn't install correctly or are missing dependencies.

If none of those work, please give more detail about the issue. The link you provided doesn't load properly, and I can't tell what you were doing beforehand that could have possibly caused this issue